# How to disable automatic creation SeriesCollection in Excel Chart

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, com

I have already this code

```
Excel::_ApplicationPtr app("Excel.Application");

app->Visible[0] = false;

Excel::_WorkbookPtr book = app->Workbooks->Add();
Excel::_WorksheetPtr sheet = book->Worksheets->Item[1];

RangePtr pRange = sheet->Cells;
RangePtr pCell;

pCell = pRange->Item[1][1]; // A1
pCell->Value2 = "1";
pCell = pRange->Item[1][2]; // B1
pCell->Value2 = "1";
pCell = pRange->Item[1][3]; // C1
pCell->Value2 = "10";

pCell = pRange->Item[2][1]; // A2
pCell->Value2 = "3";
pCell = pRange->Item[2][2]; // B2
Cell->Value2 = "1";
pCell = pRange->Item[2][3]; // C2
pCell->Value2 = "20";
```

and next

```
Excel::RangePtr pBeginRange = pRange->Item[1][1];
Excel::RangePtr pEndRange = pRange->Item[5][9];
Excel::RangePtr pTotalRange = sheet->Range[(Excel::Range *)pBeginRange][(Excel::Range *)pEndRange];

_ChartPtr  pChart2  = book->Charts->Add();
pChart2->ChartType = xlBubble3DEffect; 

pChart2->SetSourceData((Excel::Range *)pTotalRange, (long)Excel::xlColumns);
```

How to disable automatic creation SeriesCollection in Excel Chart. I want to set the ranges manually. In the automatic creation all SeriesCollection has XValues in the first column. But I needn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably can't prevent it being created, but you can delete it immediately after creating the chart, then create you own series as required.

In VBA:

```
Set Chrt = wb.Charts.Add()
Chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
```

Comment: No, This code is for VBA, but in the C++ Win32 application this don't working

Comment: [code](pChart2->SeriesCollection(_variant_t((long)1))->Delete();)  error: error C2039: 'Delete' : is not a member of 'IDispatch'
because SeriesCollection return IDispatch

Comment: Try adding intermediate results to see where it breaks (the SeriesCollection of the Chart, then Item(1) of the SeriesCollection, then apply the Delete method to the series).

Comment: after _ChartPtr  pChart2  = book->Charts->Add();  was creating default SeriesCollections. How to disable this creation or clear all default series (one method) and next I already create serios manually by NewSerios method with invoke and dispatch

Comment: This does not work if excel automatically creates more than one series

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same issue as well. From experimentation I think the following is happening:

When you create a new chart in VBA using the following code

```
Dim chSheet As Chart
Set chSheet = Charts.Add
```

Excel, trying to be helpful I bet, automatically looks at which ever worksheet your cursor had selected when you executed your code from the developer window and searches for the nearest dataset it thinks could be a range of values for the graph. This is then automatically populated in the graph. The only way around it I've found so far is to execute the following code to delete all series objects in the series collection object on the chart immediately after having created it. Touch counter intuitive but it works...

```
Public Sub DeleteChartSeries(chartSheet As Chart)

    'Shorter but perhaps less clean way of writing the code compared to below
    Do Until chartSheet.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
        chartSheet.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    'With chartSheet
    '    Do Until .seriesCollection.Count = 0
    '        .seriesCollection(1).Delete
    '    Loop
    'End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just hit a workaround: First move the cursor somewhere outside the `UsedRange`, then create the Chart: Won't do auto-detection. Then move back.

In other words, the following code works for me (Excel 2007):

```
' Assume src As Range (proposed source data for the chart) in the ActiveSheet.

' put the cursor somewhere outside the UsedRange to avoid Excel's
' 'helpful' auto detection.
Dim ur As Range
Set ur = src.Worksheet.UsedRange
ur.Cells(1, ur.Columns.Count).Offset(0, 2).Select

Dim crt As Chart
Set crt = src.Worksheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart
' ^ does NOT do auto-detection.
```